# Is it possible we can use more than one updatepanel in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible we can use more than one updatepanel below one script manager in asp.net c#.Because we can not define more than one script manager in asp.net c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course, you can use multiple UpdatePanel controls on a single page.

And yes, you only need one ScriptManager control on a single page to make your multiple UpdatePanel controls work.

Hope I was able to answer your question.